# How and where to declare Global variable that is accessible throughout my entire MVC /single page application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I am using asp.net mvc with EF . for each login session in my app in the controllers I can get the user ID for whoever is logged in using  `var userID = int.Parse(User.Identity.Name);` however I would also like to use this in other repository and service classes is the a way to initially obtain this value per session and store its value in a global variable that can be accessed by every class in solution

Comment: You don't want a global variable - since there's only one of those, different users would be overwriting each other.

Comment: I think you should always pass the userId to the repository or service classes instead of making it a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data you need to store is session level, Store the data in Session variable. eg. Session["UserId"] = userId. You can access the userid anywhere from your application for that session.eg. var userId = (int)Session["UserId"]

Answer (score 0):

In MVC the User is known in the context of a `Page` request, but that is not the case in other (repository/service/BL/DAL) classes. They do not - and should not! - have any knowledge about MVC.

You could make life easier however by creating a base class for all your controllers, implement some methods & properties there, and let the actual controllers inherit from it. Like this:

**MyBaseController.cs**

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    public int UserID
    {
        get { return int.Parse(User.Identity.Name); }
    }

    // other useful methods & properties...
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public class MyController : MyBaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = MyService.GetData(UserID);
        return View(data);
    }
}
```